# Birthday date not working

Tags: facebook, date, get

I'm developing an app which gets the birthday date of the user but it's still not working.
The most strange thing is that whe i debug this app throw the developer facebook interface, it works perfectly.
So I don't know why doesn't it want to work.
Here is my php code for getting the birthday :

```
<?php
if($user_id) {

  // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
  // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
  try {

    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=id,name,birthday', 'GET');
    print_r($user_profile);
    //echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];

  } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
    // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
    // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
    // just ask the user to login again here.
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
    echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
    error_log($e->getType());
    error_log($e->getMessage());
  }   
} else {

  // No user, print a link for the user to login
  $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
  echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

}
```

?>

Thanks to anybody

Comment: You are not asking for the permission required to get the user’ birthday. Please check the docs.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by CBroe, you need `user_birthday` in your permissions scope

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'user_birthday',
  'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.myapp.com/post_login_page'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```